# Model initialization and relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I had a model with two levels of relationships, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

`Company` which has_many `addresses`
`Address` which has many `address_types`

So if I initialize a `Company`, I assume it will create an `Address` and an `AddressType` also?

```
    @company = Company.new 
    @company.address.size #this should be 1?
    @company.address.address_type.size #this should be 1?
```

Question: How can I initialize the address, and the address_type with a default attribute, that is, the `current_user_id`

so for company in the controller, I can write:

```
@company.current_user_id = current_user.id
```

but `current_user` is not accessible in the model.  Is there a way of initializing with the current_user for everything, not just the company?  Whats the best approach to this?

can we do something like:

```
@company.address.new(current_user)
```

OR

In a before_save callback on the Address and AddressType models, could I have something like:

```
before_save: set_user

def set_user
  self.current_user_id = self.company.current_user.id
end
```

Comment: Do not forget to mark my answer as accepted, I took the time for answer you. That's how community works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you initialize the model it will start with an empty array, so:

```
@company = Company.new 
@company.address.size #this is 0
@company.address.address_type.size #this is 0
```

You can't initialize those values by default, you need to send them when creating the company.

### The Controller should tell the model instance

Working with the database is the model's job. Handling web requests, including knowing the user for the current request, is the controller's job.

Therefore, if a model instance needs to know the current user, a controller should tell it.

```
def create
  @item = Item.new
  @item.current_user = current_user # or whatever your controller method is
  ...
end
```

This assumes that Item has an attr_accessor for current_user.

### update

You can loop the resources, in your controller add a private method:

```
def assign_current_user_to_address_type(company)
  company.addresses.each do |address|
    address.address_types.each do |address_type|
      address_type.create_user_id = current_user.id
    end
  end
 
end
```

Comment: could you provide an example of how to set the create_user_id on the address and address_type in my OP?  Specifically, if a company has lots of addresses, and each address has multiple address types, how can set the current_user_id for them all?